# How do I build/install protobuf 2.4.1 on CentOs (or any LINUX/UNIX system)?

Tags: linux, unix, protocol-buffers

Ok, so I'm kind of a complete foreigner in the UNIX/LINUX land, but I need to install profbuf 2.4.1.

I was following the instructions by doing

- wget http://protobuf.googlecode.com/files/protobuf-2.4.1.tar.bz2
- tar xfj protobuf-2.4.1.tar.bz2
- pushd protobuf-2.4.1
- ./configure
- make
- sudo make install

I could only go as far as `./configure'. WHen I tried running`make`, I got some error saying "No target specified and no makefile found... Stop"

Does anyone know what I might've done wrong?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you sure `configure` ran ok ? Did it throw any errors ?

Comment: Do you really need to do that? I mean, if by any chance you're going to do your development in Java, it's not needed.

Comment: @cnicularThe configure ran, and there're a couple of lines that read "checking ...no". I assume that means, there're something missing? foch: I wish that weren't needed. But without the protobuf I can't build my maven project.

Comment: Uhm, never mind. I figured out what happened. Looks like I was missing the c++ compiler.

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't have a g++ compiler in your system or your environment variable doesn't contain the path of it. To install one on linux use the following:

```
yum install gcc-c++
```

Answer (score 1):

I had met the same question before, and now I've known the reason. It's lack of corresponding library. If you are using redhat, use root permission to enter the two lines of commands:

```
# yum install glibc-headers
# yum install gcc-c++
```

If you are using ubuntu,you can enter this:

```
# sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

I've solved my question by that way. Wish you luck!